# Windows netstat vs WMIC bytes sent/received difference

Tags: windows, networking, netstat, wmic

I'm trying to understand the difference between the bytes sent/received values returned by both netstat and wmic on Windows. I'm having a hard time finding an explanation for the significant variation.

Why is the byte count much higher when I use `netstat -e` vs `wmic path Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec`?

Here is sample output on Windows 10, with the two commands executed within seconds of each other:

```
C:\>wmic path Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface get BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec
BytesReceivedPersec  BytesSentPersec  
78940574             8900684                 
0                    0                

C:\>netstat -e
Interface Statistics

                           Received            Sent

Bytes                     395132042        45097469
Unicast packets              469727          257804
Non-unicast packets          242855            5539
Discards                          0               0
Errors                            0               4
Unknown protocols                 0
```

Comment: I used `netstat -e` to do a batch script to monitor traffic bandwidth and I found as you did, that the amount of byte reported is like 5 times greater too...